# Pivoting in Python using pd.pivot

Tags: python, pivot

I have data in the below format:

[image]

and I want to pivot this data on the Attribute column. The data should look like below after replacing `NaN` with `0`s

[image]

Comment: Try not to use images to show examples of what your data looks like. You can use the markdown to do that, and is much more likely to help you get an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am new to stack overflow and also a visual person

Comment: any small sample of dataframe will do

Comment: Location Date Attribute Value
0 AL AIN MALL BOUTIQUE 1/1/2019 Net Sales Qty 23.0
1 AL AIN MALL BOUTIQUE 1/2/2019 Net Sales Qty 15.0
2 AL AIN MALL BOUTIQUE 1/3/2019 Net Sales Qty 25.0
3 AL AIN MALL BOUTIQUE 1/4/2019 Net Sales Qty 14.0
4 AL AIN MALL BOUTIQUE 1/5/2019 Net Sales Qty 17.0